# How can I execute JavaScript onClick of a NON-LINK?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have some code that runs when a user clicks anywhere in the body of the web page. I only want the JavaScript to run if the click is on a NON-LINK. Any ideas?

Thanks
Mike

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
document.body.onclick = function(e){
    var target = e ? e.target : window.event.srcElement;
    if (target.nodeName.toLowerCase() !== 'a') {
        // Do something here...
    }
};
```

Note that any attempts to stop propagation before the event reaches the **`<body>`** will stop the above handler from running. To avoid this you can use event capturing.

Comment: Do I call this like so: <body onclick="function(e)">? Why is there a semicolon after the last brace? Thanks!

Comment: There's a semi-colon because it's a variable deceleration; and, no, you don't need to add the event obtrusively; the code above works - just put it in a SCRIPT tag somewhere within the BODY :)

Comment: This will be called on any onclick events regarding the body of the site (every event), e is passed as the element. The semicolon is there because this is assigning a block.

Comment: This will incorrectly fail on anchors, e.g. <a name="foo">Stuff about Foo</a>.

Answer (score 0):

document.body.onclick = function... is a statement.
Hence the closing ';'

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery.

```
$(function() {
   $("body").click( function() { /* your code here */ } );
   $("a").click( function(e) { e.stopPropagation(); } );
});
```

[jQuery home](http://jquery.com/).

Comment: Note: Script goes into your HTML head, you also need a reference to the jQuery library and "$(function()" is short for "$(document).ready( function()". You can find all the information you need at the jQuery site.